# I've installed Hbase but when I type a commmand in cmd "hbase shell" the it shows the following error

Tags: database, hadoop, hbase

Here is the error when I type "hbase shell"

`*:\hbase-2.5.0\hbase-config.cmd"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. \Java\jdk1.8.0_261\lib\tools.jar was unexpected at this time.`

and here comes another error when I type "start-hbase.sh"

`The file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action. please install and  app or if already installed, create an association in the Default Apps setting page`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are on windows (correct me if I'm wrong).

Your first command seems to come from an installation issue. The shell can't seem to find `hbase-config.cmd`. Make sure you followed the installation instructions properly and everything is where it's supposed to be.

As for the second error, you can't run bourne shell files (`.sh` extension) on windows.

It would be best you link the tutorial/documentation you followed in your original question, and add more information about your directory structure.

Comment: You can run shell scripts in WSL2